# Loop over 2 levels in an array and log the parent and child items?

Tags: javascript

I have key based arrays:

```
const selected = {
  1: [a, b, c],
  2: [d, e, f]
}
```

I need to loop over each item in the second level and also print its parent. So I need my output to be something like:

```
1a
1b
1c
2d
2e
3f
```

I havn't got very far. The following loggs the whole object but I expected it to run on '1' and '2'

```
Array.of(selected).forEach((item)=>{
  console.log(item)
});
```

Im using babel so happy to use ES6 for the solution.

Comment: Why is `selected` an object with numeric keys instead of an actual array? And `Array.from(selected)` will just wrap `selected` in an array.

Comment: where are you getting `3f` from?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All you need is `Object.entries` with `.forEach()` and a nested loop.

```js
const selected = {
  1: ['a', 'b', 'c'],
  2: ['d', 'e', 'f']
};
Object.entries(selected)
  .forEach(([key, arr]) => arr.forEach(v => console.log(key + v)));
```

The `Array.from` would work instead of `Array.of` if you had a `.length`, though you'd have a sparse array.

---

```js
const selected = {
  1: ['a', 'b', 'c'],
  2: ['d', 'e', 'f'],
  length: 3,
};
Array.from(selected)
   .forEach((arr, i) => arr && arr.forEach(v => console.log(i + v)));
```

Answer (score 0):

[`Object.entries()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/entries) is great:

```js
const selected = {
  1: ['a', 'b', 'c'],
  2: ['d', 'e', 'f']
};
Object.entries(selected).forEach(([key, value]) => {
  value.forEach(v => console.log(key + v));
});
```